# Custom Session Pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, session

We use a student information system called Colleague that is developed by Ellucian.  As far as I can tell, the system does not use any sort of session pool so rapidly opening and closing connections to the database is both expensive/slow and can use up a lot of resources on the server side.  In response I developed a session manager to help facilitate parallel and multi-threaded programming.

The code is simple and should be straight forward however seeing how this type of code is hard to test and debug I thought I would get a second opinion.  Especially let me know if you find any issues that might lead to race conditions or deadlocks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Person.Colleague
{
    public class SessionManager : IDisposable
    {
        public int NumberOfSessions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.numberOfSessions;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.Started)
                    return;
                this.numberOfSessions = value;
            }
        }

        public bool Started
        {
            get
            {
                return this.started;
            }

            private set
            {
                this.started = value;
            }
        }

        private int numberOfSessions = 0;
        private int offSet = 0;
        private bool started = false;
        private ConcurrentDictionary<int, ManagedSession> sessionList;
        private object sessionListLock = new object();
        private object instanceLock = new object();
        private string username = String.Empty;
        private string password = String.Empty;

        public SessionManager(int numberOfSessions)
        {
            this.numberOfSessions = numberOfSessions;
            this.sessionList = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ManagedSession>(5, this.numberOfSessions);
        }

        public void Start(string username = "", string password = "", string colleagueAccountName = "production")
        {
            if (this.Started)
                return;

            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;

            lock (instanceLock)
            {
                lock (sessionListLock)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < this.numberOfSessions; x++)
                    {
                        this.sessionList.TryAdd(x, new ManagedSession(x, this.username, this.password, colleagueAccountName));
                        this.sessionList[x].InUse = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            this.Started = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            this.Started = false;
            // THIS METHOD WILL TRY TO GRACEFULLY CLOSE ALL THE OPEN COLLEAGUE SESSIONS
            // IT WILL LOOP THROUGH ALL THE OPEN CONNECTIONS CLOSING THEM ONE AT A TIME
            // IF THE CONNECTION IS CURRENTLY CHECKED OUT IT WILL SKIP THAT ONE AND TRY
            // AGAIN AFTER WAITING 1 SECOND IF AFTER 30 SEONCDS ALL THE CONNECTIONS HAVE
            // NOT CHECKED IN AND BEEN CLOSED THEY WILL BE FORCED
            lock (instanceLock)
            {
                int closedCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < this.numberOfSessions; x++)
                    {
                        if (!this.sessionList[x].InUse)
                        {
                            this.sessionList[x].Session.Close();
                            closedCount++;    
                        }
                    }
                    if (closedCount == this.numberOfSessions)
                        break;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait one second

                    // FORCE THE THE SESSIONS TO CLOSE
                    if (i == 29 && closedCount != this.numberOfSessions)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < this.numberOfSessions; x++)
                        {
                            this.sessionList[x].Session.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public ManagedSession CheckOutSession(int sessionID = -1)
        {
            if (!this.Started)
                throw new SessionManagerNotStartedException("Cannot check out a new session. The SessionManager object is either shutting down or was never started.");

            int attemptCount = 0;
            int offSetAdjusted = 0;

            if (sessionID != -1 && this.sessionList[sessionID].InUse)
                throw new SessionAlreadyCheckedOutException(sessionID);

            while (sessionID == -1)
            {
                lock (sessionListLock)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfSessions; i++)
                    {
                        // OFFSET WHERE WE START CHECKING FOR A FREE SESSION SO WE ROTATE
                        // THROUGH THEM INSTEAD OF USING THE FIRST FEW SESSIONS OVER 
                        // AND OVER IN LOW USE SCENARIOS
                        offSetAdjusted = offSet + i;
                        if (offSetAdjusted >= this.numberOfSessions)
                            offSetAdjusted -= this.numberOfSessions;
                        if (!this.sessionList[offSetAdjusted].InUse)
                        {
                            this.sessionList[offSetAdjusted].InUse = true;
                            sessionID = offSetAdjusted;
                            if (this.sessionList[sessionID].Session == null)
                            {
                                this.sessionList[sessionID].Session = new ColleagueSession();
                                this.sessionList[sessionID].Session.Open(this.username, this.password);
                            }
                            if (this.sessionList[sessionID].Session.IsActive == false)
                            {
                                this.sessionList[sessionID].Session.Open(this.username, this.password);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    this.offSet = this.offSet + 1;
                    if (this.offSet >= this.numberOfSessions)
                        this.offSet = 0;
                }
                if (sessionID != -1)
                    break;

                attemptCount = attemptCount + 1;
                if (attemptCount > 500)
                    throw new SessionCheckOutTimedOutException();

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
            }

            return this.sessionList[sessionID];
        }

        public void CheckInSession(ManagedSession managedSession)
        {
            this.sessionList[managedSession.SessionID].InUse = false;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Stop();
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            this.Stop();
        }

        public int NumberOfActiveSessions()
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (ManagedSession managedSession in this.sessionList.Values)
            {
                if (managedSession.Session.IsActive)
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        public int NumberOfCheckedOutSessions()
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (ManagedSession managedSession in this.sessionList.Values)
            {
                if (managedSession.InUse)
                    count++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        public void RefreshSessions(int sessionID = -1)
        {
            int[] sessionIDs;
            if (sessionID != -1)
                sessionIDs = new int[] { sessionID };
            else
                sessionIDs = this.sessionList.Keys.ToArray();

            int attemptCount = 0;
            foreach (int ID in sessionIDs)
            {
                attemptCount = 0;
                bool success = false;
                if (this.sessionList.Keys.Contains(ID))
                {
                    while (success == false)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            ManagedSession managedSession = this.CheckOutSession(ID);
                            managedSession.RefreshSession();
                            this.CheckInSession(managedSession);
                            success = true;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            if (ex is Person.Colleague.SessionManager.SessionAlreadyCheckedOutException)
                            {
                                attemptCount = attemptCount + 1;
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                            }
                        }
                        if (attemptCount > 5)
                            throw new SessionRefreshTimeOutException(ID);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new BadSessionIDException();
                }
            }
        }

        public class ManagedSession
        {
            public Person.Colleague.ColleagueSession Session
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.session;
                }
                internal set
                {
                    this.Session = value;
                }
            }

            public int SessionID
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.sessionID;
                }
            }
            internal bool InUse { get; set; }
            private string Username { get; set; }
            private string Password { get; set; }
            private string ColleagueAccountName { get; set; }

            private ColleagueSession session;
            private int sessionID;

            internal ManagedSession(int sessionID, string username = null, string password = null, string colleagueAccountName = null)
            {
                this.Username = username;
                this.Password = password;
                this.ColleagueAccountName = colleagueAccountName;

                this.session = new Colleague.ColleagueSession();
                this.session.Open(this.Username, this.Password, ColleagueAccountName);
                this.sessionID = sessionID;
            }

            public void RefreshSession()
            {
                if (this.session != null)
                {
                    this.session.Close();
                    this.session.Open(this.Username, this.Password, this.session.ColleagueAccountName);
                    if (this.session.ColleagueInitialized)
                    {
                        this.session.ColleagueInitialized = false;
                        this.session.InitializeColleagueConnection();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class SessionRefreshTimeOutException : Exception
        {
            public int SessionID { get; set; }

            public SessionRefreshTimeOutException(int sessionID) { this.SessionID = sessionID; }
            public SessionRefreshTimeOutException(int sessionID, string message) : base(message) { this.SessionID = sessionID; }
            public SessionRefreshTimeOutException(int sessionID, string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { this.SessionID = sessionID; }
            protected SessionRefreshTimeOutException(
              System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
              System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
                : base(info, context) { }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class SessionManagerNotStartedException : Exception
        {
            public SessionManagerNotStartedException() { }
            public SessionManagerNotStartedException(string message) : base(message) { }
            public SessionManagerNotStartedException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
            protected SessionManagerNotStartedException(
              System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
              System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
                : base(info, context) { }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class SessionCheckOutTimedOutException : Exception
        {
            public SessionCheckOutTimedOutException() { }
            public SessionCheckOutTimedOutException(string message) : base(message) { }
            public SessionCheckOutTimedOutException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
            protected SessionCheckOutTimedOutException(
              System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
              System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
                : base(info, context) { }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class BadSessionIDException : Exception
        {
            public BadSessionIDException() { }
            public BadSessionIDException(string message) : base(message) { }
            public BadSessionIDException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
            protected BadSessionIDException(
              System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
              System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
                : base(info, context) { }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class SessionAlreadyCheckedOutException : Exception
        {
            public int SessionID { get; set; }

            public SessionAlreadyCheckedOutException(int sessionID) { this.SessionID = sessionID; }
            public SessionAlreadyCheckedOutException(int sessionID, string message) : base(message) { this.SessionID = sessionID; }
            public SessionAlreadyCheckedOutException(int sessionID, string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { this.SessionID = sessionID; }
            protected SessionAlreadyCheckedOutException(
              System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
              System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
                : base(info, context) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try profiling the database/application before taking this route (ex: configure connection pooling) instead. What you trying to do is quite hard and requires some level of expertise that I don't think you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> public Person.Colleague.ColleagueSession Session
> {
>     get
>     {
>         return this.session;
>     }
>     internal set
>     {
>         this.Session = value;
>     }
> }
> ```

There's a typo in the setter, it should be `this.session = value;`. As it stands, calling the setter will cause the program to crash. You can avoid typos like this by using [auto-implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), e.g.

```
public Person.Colleague.ColleagueSession Session { get; internal set; }
```